# ImageIO.read is terminating the program without error

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, imageicon

Lol, I completely failed a moment ago. Uploaded the code after deleting something.

Anyway, I got the background to load using ImageIcons, but I'm trying to use a BufferedImage because that's how I was told you have to do it to draw more images on top of it.

The BufferedImage returns no errors, but doesn't draw anything.

Code is below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client {
    static JFrame client = new JFrame();

    public static void drawBackground() throws IOException {
        BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("Resources/Images/Background.png"));
        client.setTitle("Keldagrim: The lost Empire");
        client.setSize(1280, 720);
        client.setDefaultCloseOperation(client.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Container pane = client.getContentPane();
        BackgroundPanel backgroundPanel = new BackgroundPanel(background);
        pane.add(backgroundPanel);
        client.pack();
        client.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void drawLogin() {
        ImagePanel loginBox = new ImagePanel(new ImageIcon("Resources/Images/LoginBox.png").getImage());
        client.add(loginBox);
        client.repaint();
        System.out.println("Painted");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            drawBackground();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        drawLogin();
    }

}

    class ImagePanel extends JPanel {

    private Image img;

    public ImagePanel(String img) {
        this(new ImageIcon(img).getImage());
    }

    public ImagePanel(Image img) {
        this.img = img;
        Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
        setPreferredSize(size);
        setMinimumSize(size);
        setMaximumSize(size);
        setSize(size);
        setLayout(null);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }

}


class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    BufferedImage backgroundImage;
    public BackgroundPanel(BufferedImage image){
        backgroundImage = image;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(backgroundImage, null, 50,50);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `e.printStackTrace();` to begin with.

Comment: You never call `drawClient`, therefore it never starts the Event Dispatching Thread and when the execution reaches the end of the main method, the JVM is terminating (as there are no more non-daemon threads running)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of things that aren't going right for you...

1. You're not acutally calling `drawClient` any where, so the frame is never been created.  I would actually get rid of this method, as it is not adding any value and is, actually confusing the problem.
2. You're using a static reference to the background image, which means that only one image can ever be used through out your entire application, regardless of how many "Client" panels you create.  You then pass that reference to the panel anyway, which is a waste.
3. While you should really be logging errors (and displaying an error message) at the very least you should be dumping the stack trace to the console, it will make your life much easier.
4. Call `setVisible` AFTER you've finished setting up the frame, funny things happen if you don't

Try using something like...

```
public class Client extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    public Client(Image backgroundImage) {
        this.backgroundImage = backgroundImage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }

                BufferedImage background = null;
                try {
                    background = ImageIO.read(new File("Resources/Images/Background.png"));
                    JFrame client = new JFrame();
                    client.setTitle("Keldagrim: The lost Empire");
                    client.setSize(1280, 720);
                    client.setDefaultCloseOperation(client.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    client.setContentPane(new Client(background));
                    client.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also, as a side note, you're not actually painting the background, but I suspect that's another question ;)

Try taking a look at

- [How to create a UI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (backgroundImage != null) {
         Client c =   new Client(backgroundImage);
         c.drawClient();
} else {
            System.out.println("Error: No background Image.");
}
```

Comment: To add onto this: use `this` instead of creating a new client instance in the drawClient method.

Comment: `Client` is a panel.  It can't be made to display on the screen without some kind of window...

Comment: @Legend I'd either make it static or, personally, get rid of it, as it's not adding any value